# mysql select * or desired parameters in php function

Tags: php, mysql, class, function

I have a function which selects the * values from a particular table, I need to configure that if I pass * in parameter then it selects all or the selected parameters.

My function is as follows:

```
  public function select($tablename){
          $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
          if(!$select){
              echo "cant select table mane";
              }
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

              print_r($row);
              }
          }
```

How can I pass the dynamic colum name in place of *

Comment: Avoid mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: you should have searched it before posting here

Answer (score 1):

```
public function select($tablename,$column=NULL){
      if($column == null) {
          $select = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM $tablename");
      } else {
          $select = mysql_query("SELECT ".$column."  FROM $tablename");
      }
```

call it using `select("abcd_table","id,name");` **OR** for all just `select("abcd_table");`

By **Alex**

```
Avoid mysql, it is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more parameter `$columnname` type array in your function.

```
   public function select($tablename,$columnname = array()){
      if(count($columnname)){
         $columnname = implode(",",$columnname);
         $select = mysql_query("SELECT {$columnname} FROM $tablename");
      }  
      else{
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
      }
      #code continue
   }
```

Calling will be like below

To select all fields,

```
select($tablename);
```

To select some fields,

```
select($tablename,array('field','field2'));
```

Note: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

That's even easier:

```
public function select( $tablename , $columnName = array() ){
   $columnName = $columnName ? implode( ',' , $columnName ) : '*';
   $select     = mysql_query( 'SELECT ' . $columnName . ' FROM ' . $tableName );
   if(!$select){
      echo "cant select table mane";
   }
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
      print_r($row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function select($tablename,$column="*"){

          $select = mysql_query("SELECT $column FROM $tablename");
          if(!$select){
              echo "cant select table mane";
              }
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

              print_r($row);
              }
          }
```

call like `select("table","*") or` 
call like `select("table","col1,col2")`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function select($tablename, $selectrow){
          $select = mysql_query("SELECT $selectrow FROM $tablename");
          if(!$select){
              echo "cant select table mane";
          }
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
              print_r($row);
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this modified function

```
public function select($tablename,$array_fields){
    if(!empty($array_fields)){
      $fieldstr = implode(',',$array_fields);
      $fieldstr = trim($fieldstr,',');
    }else{
        $fieldstr = '*';
    }
      $select = mysql_query("SELECT $fieldstr FROM $tablename");
      if(!$select){
          echo "cant select table mane";
          }
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){

          print_r($row);
          }
```

}